# Setting User-Agent Header in Scala with Databinders Dispatch Library

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 15):

You need to append your request with the header info, using the <:< operator. Like this :

```
url("http://example.com") <:< Map("User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just from reading the source, it looks like you're supposed to call http.client.params.setParameter("User-Agent","Cowbells") on your Http object.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://static.javadoc.io/net.databinder.dispatch/dispatch-core_2.11/0.11.2/index.html#dispatch.Req) will work as well:

```
url("http://example.com").addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla...")
```