# Methods to insert Oauth headers in Scala Dispatch 0.9.5?

Tags: scala, http, http-headers, scala-dispatch

Using the rather simple and elegant Scala Dispatch HTTP library. Since the Twitter Search API is now using OAuth 1.0A, I obviously need to start injecting Consumer and AccessToken information. I've got a simple request below:

```
val request = url("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23%sresult_type=mixed&count=4" format w.queryValue)
val response = Http(request OK as.String)
```

What's a way to add headers to this if I already know my Consumer and AccessToken information? The documentation is rather scarce. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the OAuth API, but Dispatch allows you to add arbitrary HTTP Request headers with the `<:<` method/operator.

So mashing together your code example above and this ["Authorizing a request"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) example from Twitter's Developer site, you might get something like this:

```
val authentication = """OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog", oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",  oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1318622958", oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", oauth_version="1.0""""

val request = url("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23%sresult_type=mixed&count=4" format w.queryValue)
val authHeader = Map("Authentication" -> authentication) 
val requestWithAuthentication = request <:< authHeader
val response = Http(requestWithAuthentication OK as.String)
```

I haven't verified whether this actually works, but hopefully it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Credit where credit is due: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394667/setting-user-agent-header-in-scala-with-databinders-dispatch-library is what reminded me about the `<:<` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this with dispatch:

```
private def buildSearchReq(searchTerm: String, lat: Double, long: Double): Req = {
  val consumer = new ConsumerKey(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
  val requestToken = new RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)
  val req = url(searchUrl)
    .addQueryParameter("term", searchTerm)
    .addQueryParameter("radius_filter", "40000")
    .addQueryParameter("ll", s"$lat,$long")
  new SigningVerbs(req).sign(consumer, requestToken)
}
```

You could also do something more like this if you wanted:

```
private def buildSearchReq(searchTerm: String, lat: Double, long: Double): Req = {
  val req = url(searchUrl) <<? Map("term" -> searchTerm, "radius_filter" -> "40000", "ll" -> s"$lat,$long")
  new SigningVerbs(req).sign(new ConsumerKey(consumerKey, consumerSecret), new RequestToken(token, tokenSecret))
}
```

There are probably even more terse ways of doing it, but you get the idea.